# Android Studio keeps adding additional files to GitHub

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.2, using the built in VCS tool. For some reason, Android Studio automatically adds a bunch of extra xml files and folders that I did not add nor edit.

More specifically, it's adding the following files when I don't want it to:

```
/_windows
IntelliLang.xml
debugger.xml
diff.xml
vcs.xml
web-browsers.xml
```

This makes making pull requests downright impossible as the master branch doesn't have these files, and none of my other group members seem to have this problem either.

Any help in removing / configuring Android Studio to stop this pesky bug?

--

edit: I am already using a gitignore file already. The weird thing is that my additional files are in the wrong folder too. Basically, my root folder, has a subfolder for my app. All the junk files are created in my root folder for some reason by Android Studio.

```
/root/
    /_windows
    IntelliLang.xml
    debugger.xml
    diff.xml
    vcs.xml
    web-browsers.xml

    /my_android_app/
                    gitignore for my app
                    /files actually needed for my project
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this feature is called "Settings Repository", and it's intended to save IDE settings automatically. I guess I might accidentally agree on some popup from IDEA which look like add files to the git repository, so this started working.

FIX: Open Preferences → Tools → Settings Repository → Delete. I also disabled Auto-Sync. Dunno where it's going to save if I delete everything, but I switch it off to be extra safe..

Answer (score 0):

If the IDE you are using is adding files that it requires, but which you don't want to be included in your repository, then this is a good candidate for additions to your .gitingore file.

Are you currently using a .gitignore file?

More information can be found here:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

You basically add an entry for each file or folder you want to ignore, and as a result, git will no longer try to include these files in commits going forward.

There is a good resource here:

https://github.com/github/gitignore

For creating a default .gitignore file.  You would pick the .gitignore template that closely matches the type of development that you are doing, and customize from there.  For example, I always start with the default Visual Studio template.

Probably the best suggestion would be to use the template .gitignore file for Android Development which is located here:

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore

**NOTE:** I would copy the contents of this linked file into this answer, however, these template .gitignore files are always changing, as new recommendations are being added.  It is best to keep referring to the source file for the most up to date version.

It doesn't explicitly ignore the files that you have mentioned, but it could be that those files are created within a folder that is being ignored.

Comment: I am using a gitignore file at the moment, which is the one recommended for Android Studio. Please see my edit for additional info, I probably should have mentioned it before.

Comment: Did you start using the gitignore file before this problem started happening? Or did you try to retrospectively apply the .gittgnore file?  When these files appear as changes within git, do they appear as modifications, or as new files?

Comment: When I first forked and cloned my project, the gitignore was already there. The changes don't appear in Git, it seems that Android Studio is automatically adding/committing/pushing to the repo for me. It creates just about one commit per file, each of the format `AI-2.2.2 <user@device_name Update diff.xml Create vcs.xml`, which really bloats my commit history. (Group assignment monitors git usage)

Comment: Sorry, but this is getting into an area (Android Studio) that I am not really familiar with.  Seems like the problem that you are having is far different than what I originally thought.  If Android Studio is making direct changes to your repo (which is quite surprising, I certainly would expect that from my IDE) then nothing in a .gitignore file will help.  You will need to figure out where, and why, that integration is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use gitIgnore file.. i am currently using this .

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
.externalNativeBuild
/captures
```

check if the same works for you or not ..

if you want to know the details  please check [here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore)