# Strange automatic commits (Android Studio, GitKraken, Ubuntu)?

Tags: android, git, ubuntu, github, gitkraken

I'm working on an Android project for my company.

Here is my current development setup:

- Android Studio (version 2.3)
- GitKraken (version 2.1.0)
- Ubuntu (version 16.04)

As I make improvements to my project in Android Studio, I use GitKraken to review my changes and commit them to GitHub. Nothing out of the ordinary.

My problem is that every once in awhile, files will be committed directly to my 'master' branch and pushed directly to GitHub - without me doing anything. The files that are pushed are configuration .xml files that I haven't changed. This is very frustrating, for obvious reasons. The commit message that is generated usually looks like:

- AI-2.3 trent@trent-Lenovo-Yoga-3-14 Create hg.xml

I have deleted my 'master' branch completely (local and GitHub), and created a new branch called 'stable' to take it's place. That didn't work, as these 'auto commits' simply create 'master' branch again and push it to GitHub.

I have also turned off VCS settings in Android Studio. I cannot find any setting in GitKraken would be doing this - to my knowledge, anyway.

I'm hoping that I'm unaware of a simple setting that can stop this behavior. I've searched for similar issues on Google, Android Studio forums, and Stack Overflow, with no luck.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Did you found why this is coming?

Comment: Nope, I never did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same problem with Android Studio 2.3.3 and Ubuntu 16.04.
The problem occurred after Android Studio (AS) glitch when it lost my private IDE settings.

Solution: look into dir `~/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/settingsRepository` (take notes that `.AndroidStudio2.3` is hidden dir). In my case, there is `repository` dir that contains my Project plus all that wired additional setting files that been added to my GitHub master branch every time I've Push. Just delete that `repository` dir.

Looks like AS use its own source control system on top of Git. As I can see some people even use it for backing up their settings:
https://github.com/kakkoyun/android-studio-settings
https://github.com/xinthink/android-studio-settings

Didn't go dip into the problem, just solve it for my case. Would be good if any Expert explain that strange Android Studio behavior in more details.

Also related to [Android Studio keeps adding additional files to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40583568/android-studio-keeps-adding-additional-files-to-github/40583843)

Comment: Deleting that directory solved my problem completely. Thank you very much! I've been looking for a way to stop this behavior for a long time.