# Android Studio's Dracula Color Scheme Got Messed Up?

Tags: android-studio

Allowed for some plugin updates in Android Studio, and now my color scheme got 'messed up.' Parts of the interface is now white and grey??

What happened??
[image]

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Have you tried reselecting the theme?

Comment: Yes, I did cache and restart as well as reselect the theme.....no good. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Android Studio itself was the culprit. It was saving its settings in one of my regular repositories. I was trying to figure out where these files were coming from!
When I got rid of the rpository setting, the colours came back!

Who knew!

[Android Studio keeps adding additional files to GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50451875/8692691)